AWS Quicksight: How to control access to certain DynamoDB Tables
So I tried to used to Lambda connector that AWS offers when trying to connect Athena with DynamoDB. The problem is that it gets all the DynamoDB tables, I want to only show production tables (which ends with the DbProd suffix). Is there a way crawl only those tables automatically? I know that AWS Glue has a crawler, but it seems like I have to add table by table name manually. Is there an automatic way to do this?

1
Q: I want to only show production tables (which ends with the DbProd suffix).
A: At least for now, you can't do that if you use default database or using template lambda from aws. Either create custom lambda code instead of using template from aws or create custom database with supplemental metadata and create glue tables that what you want only.
2
Q: I know that AWS Glue has a crawler, but it seems like I have to add table by table name manually.
A: You only do that manually if your table name contains a character that not permitted by glue, for example capital letter. Glue crawler minimize your effort to do this but i dont recommend this to you because it will crawl your entire dynamo db tables. I suggest you to create table by table manually with supplemental metadata properties.
source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-dynamodb.html#connectors-dynamodb-setting-up-databases-and-tables-in-aws-glue
